# Is this a total ordering of the set of full labelled binary trees?

Tags: trees, binary

Consider a binary tree labelled by some ordered set of *letters*. Traversing the tree in preorder determines a sequence of letters - a *word*.

A binary tree is called *full* if all its non-leaf vertices have exactly two children.

Given two such binary trees that are also full, and determine the same word, does it follow that the two trees are equal?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you understand the definitions? Have you tried coming up with small examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will definitely be more than one full binary tree that will yield a particular pre-order traversal. So short answer to your question will be no.

Here is a sketch for a potential counter-example. Consider the following 2 trees.

[image]

[image]

There will exist an assignment of letters such that the pre-order traversal on both the above trees yields the same word. However, the trees are clearly dissimilar, and hence your claim is false.